# Get file path from file name in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net

I was coding an application which lists files of a folder in a ListBox, and when an item is selected, I need its path for deleting, moving, and copying it.

The problem is that I load items from a folder using the following code:

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(My.Settings.sapath & "\cleo", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.cs")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(foundFile)
Next
```

and the result is this:

[image]

The ListBox shows the entire path of file. I just want to show the file name and get its path from it, so that I can do copy / paste stuff.

Comment: You cant get the path from just the file name.  Once it is removed it is lost.  You can use a FileInfo collection as the datasource and display just the filename though.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a DataSource, and set the ValueMember and DisplayMember differently. So you display one thing, but you can pull out another.

```
' Your original array of filenames. I made my own array for testing.
' For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(My.Settings.sapath & "\cleo", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.cs")
Dim foundFiles = {"c:\tests1\test1.cs", "c:\tests2\test2.cs", "c:\tests3\test3.cs"}
' An anonymous type is returned with Path and FileName
' You can change the formatting and logic here
Dim foundFilesAndNames = From f In foundFiles
                         Select New With {.Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(f),
                                          .FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f)
                                         }
ListBox1.DataSource = foundFilesAndNames.ToList()
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "FileName"
ListBox1.ValueMember = "Path"
' Remove any existing event handlers before adding a new one (alternatively can be done with IDE)
RemoveHandler ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, Nothing
AddHandler ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged,
    Sub()
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Selected value: '{0}'", ListBox1.SelectedValue))
    End Sub
```

When clicking on the ListBox (changing the selected index), you can now extract the path from the `ValueMember` with `ListBox1.SelectedValue`

[image]

Comment: Also a custom class which overrides ToString(), pretty reusable.

Comment: If it's required to store three logical properties of the full path, I'd agree. In this case however I'd just use an anonymous class. It is pretty much all contained in a few lines of code.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly OK. I just wanted to mention an alternative handy if you already have an object you have to deal with!

Comment: Good point, DisplayMember and ValueMember can work with any class, anonymous or not! Thanks

Comment: i'm  having trouble with this code it says "Name 'Path' is either not declared or not in the current scope"

Comment: @gauravm which line?

Comment: @GauravM I fixed it. You probably just need the namespace `System.IO.` before Path, or you could also just put `Imports System.IO` at the top of your code.